# Facebook post custom action to timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have created a custom action that I want to allow users to post to their timeline with e.g. {User} read {Article}.  I can get this to work fine when I do a post using the sample URL like this :

```
    FB.api('/me/fbsite:actionname' + 
'?object=http://samples.ogp.me/356694057772404&access_token=abc','post'
```

But when I replace the sample URL with my own URL I get the error 'The session was invalidated explicitly using an API call'.  Can anybody please advise?

EDIT : Changed my Javascript to this, but I now get 'Invalid OAuth Access Token' :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redeem() {
    FB.api('/me/fbsite:actionname' +
   '?object=http://samples.ogp.me/356694057772404&access_token=\' + <%=UserManager.Current.FB.accessToken %>  + \'', 'post',
   function (response) {
       var msg = 'Error occured';
       if (!response || response.error) {
           if (response.error) {
               msg += "\n\nType: " + response.error.type + "\n\nMessage: " + response.error.message;
           }
           alert(msg);
       }
       else {
           alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be because you are using the same access token in same session. So try logging out and log back in, get a new FB access token, and try the query using the new access token you got, that should work as expected.